# React Native - Increase Circle Size and then Decrease

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a simple circle tapping game with react native for learning purposes.

What I am trying to do is render some circles with random locations on screen with small radius then increase it up to a value, after decrease it and finally remove the circle from screen - just like in this game:
http://mouseaccuracy.com/

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  View,
  ToastAndroid
} from "react-native";

const { width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class BestGameEver extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      circles: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(this.spawner, 1000);
    setInterval(this.updateCircle, 16);
  }

  updateCircle = () => {
    this.state.circles.map((circle, i) => {
      if (
        circle.width < 50 &&
        circle.height < 50 &&
        circle.borderRadius < 50 &&
        circle.increase == true
      ) {
        circle.width = circle.width + 1;
        circle.height = circle.height + 1;
        circle.borderRadius = circle.borderRadius + 1;

        var array = this.state.circles;
        array.splice(i, 1);
        array.push(circle);
        this.setState({ circles: array });
      } else if (
        circle.width == 50 &&
        circle.height == 50 &&
        circle.borderRadius == 50
      ) {
        circle.increase = false;
      }
      if (circle.increase == false) {
        circle.width = circle.width - 1;
        circle.height = circle.height - 1;
        circle.borderRadius = circle.borderRadius - 1;

        var array = this.state.circles;
        array.splice(i, 1);
        array.push(circle);
        this.setState({ circles: array });
      }

      if (circle.width == 0 && circle.height == 0 && circle.borderRadius == 0) {
        ToastAndroid.show("removing", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        var array = this.state.circles;
        array.splice(i, 1);
        this.setState({ circles: array });
      }
    });
  };
  spawner = () => {
    var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (WIDTH - 0 + 1) + 0);
    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (HEIGHT - 0 + 1) + 0);

    var circle = {
      increase: true,
      x: randomX,
      y: randomY,
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
      borderRadius: 5
    };
    this.setState({ circles: [...this.state.circles, circle] });
  };
  renderCircles = () => {
    if (this.state.circles.length != 0) {
      return this.state.circles.map((circle, i) => {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              backgroundColor: "blue",
              width: circle.width,
              height: circle.height,
              borderRadius: circle.borderRadius,
              left: circle.x,
              top: circle.y
            }}
          />
        );
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <View style={styles.container}>{this.renderCircles()}</View>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF"
  }
});
```

Currently I can spawn circles on screen every 5 second then increase their size up to 50 with the updateCircle function.

How do i then decrease the size of circle once it has reached up to 50?

thanks

edit:
I updated my question now i can decrease but its lagging for some reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You may add a new variable to track whether it is in increasing mode or decreasing mode. If it's increasing mode initially, run current logic. If it's in decreasing mode, add new block of code to reduce circle size down to 0 or whatever.

Comment: hello i edited my question now i can decrease but its lagging ?

Comment: You should optimize your logic somewhere else. The answer is strictly related to your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated) API. An `Animated.Value()` can be bound to a style property in an `Animated.View`. Then you can change that `Animated.Value` and the style change will be reflected automatically for the view.

You'd use `<Animated.View>` components for the circles, then use a single `Animated.Value()` for each circle to style its `width`, `height`, and `borderRadius` (you'll probably need `Animated.divide()` for the border radius). Then you could use `Animated.timing()` and `Animated.sequence()` to tween that circle's value up, then down. All of that could be set immediately after each circle was created.

You'll get much better performance, since the instructions can be sent to the native code once per circle, instead of once per circle per frame of animation.